# How make from one dataframe, a bigger dataframe with the same values

Tags: r

I have 12x2 dataset. I want to create a data frame of size 48x9 (same values as in initial dataframe). one solution that I found is doing 3 times `rbind()` and then 4 times `cbind()`. How can I quickly do it without writing multiple times `cbind` and `rbind`?

I found following solution `test<-df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), each = 5), ]`, however it does not preserve the order of values as in the initial dataframe.

data is following

```
structure(list(Group.1 = 1:12, x = c(-1.44379403794038, -0.662282958199357, 
NA, NA, 11.6111730205279, 15.479, 17.8206451612903, 16.7009384164223, 
12.9984545454545, 7.88973607038123, NA, 0.793225806451613)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I am sorry, could you please provide the data through `dput()`? Also, 4x10 means 4 rows and 10 columns or just 40 datasets with random size?

Comment: I added to the question. 12x2 means 12 rows and 2 columns

Answer (score 1):

I found solution by using `do.call("rbind", replicate(3, df, simplify = FALSE))`, the same logic is also for columns